# Convert a string into a multidimensional arrays with different lengths

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, command-line, args

I need to execute by command line a code that will provide a multidimensional array with elements with not necessarily equal lengths.

The execution string is bellow:

```
start /wait java -jar testMSMWithIndex.jar Foursquare_weather_day_root-type_type 0,1,2-4
```

I'm considering to pass the parameter `0,1,2-4` and then convert it in a multidimensional array with elements of different lengths in this case, i.e. `{{0}, {1}, {2, 4}}`.

Note that `{{0, null}, {1, null}, {2, 4}}` does not work to my problem.

Do you guys know how to develop a method or even get directly as an array from args?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: I would split on `,`. Then I would check the lengths. If the length is one, I would add that to an array. If the length is greater than one, I would split on `-`. I would then loop from the starting number to the end number (inclusively). In the loop, I would add those numbers to an array.

Answer (score 2):

It's doubtful that anything already exists to do this for you, so you'll have to parse the string for yourself.  Something like this would do it:

```java
public static int[][] parseRaggedArrayFromString(String s)
        throws NumberFormatException {
    String[] ss = s.split(",");
    int[][] result = new int[ss.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < ss.length; ++i) {
        if (!ss[i].contains("-")) {
            result[i] = new int[1];
            result[i][0] = Integer.parseInt(ss[i]);
        } else {
            String[] range = ss[i].split("-", 2);
            int lo = Integer.parseInt(range[0]);
            int hi = Integer.parseInt(range[1]);
            int size = hi - lo + 1;
            result[i] = new int[size > 0 ? size : 1];
            int j = 0;
            do {
                result[i][j] = lo;
                ++lo;
                ++j;
            } while (lo <= hi);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's basically a split on `,` and `-`. From there is just handling the data. Comments in the code.

```java
/**
 * @author sedj601
 */
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "0,1,2-3";

        String[] firstArray = input.split(",");//Split on ,.
        String[][] outputArray = new String[firstArray.length][];//The array that will be holding the output

        //Used to process the firstArray
        for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
            if (firstArray[i].length() > 1) {//If the lenght is greater than one. split on -.
                String[] secondArray = firstArray[i].split("-");
                //Subtract the two numbers and add one to get the lenght of the array that will hold these values
                int arrayLength = Integer.parseInt(secondArray[1]) - Integer.parseInt(secondArray[0]) + 1;
                String[] tempArray = new String[arrayLength];
                int increment = 0;//Keeps up with the tempArray index.
                //loop from the first number to the last number inclusively.
                for (int t = Integer.parseInt(secondArray[0]); t <= Integer.parseInt(secondArray[1]); t++) {
                    tempArray[increment++] = Integer.toString(t);//Add the data to the array.
                }
                outputArray[i] = tempArray;//Add the array to the output array.
            } else {//If the lenght is 1, creat an array and add the current data.
                String[] tempArray = new String[1];
                tempArray[0] = firstArray[i];
                outputArray[i] = tempArray;
            }
        }

        //Print the output.
        for (String[] x : outputArray) {
            for (String y : x) {
                System.out.print(y + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
--- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) @ JavaTestingGround ---
0 
1 
2 3 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  1.194 s
Finished at: 2021-01-08T00:08:15-06:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I really think that's possible when you create an array of type `Object` .(not a good idea) Since multi-D arrays can only hold arrays of same length (`int[][]`). Then you create and retrieve values from array by casting...
I am trying here to be creative and adopt to your requirements..

```java
public class x {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[] arguments = new Object[args.length];
// Then make a loop to capture arguments in array..
// or add manually
    arguments[0] = new String[]{args[0]};
    arguments[1] = new String[]{args[1],args[2]};
//Then retrieve info from object later by casting
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString((String[]) arguments[1]));
  }
}
...
```

Although, please consider using a collection...

Comment: In fact, it is possible to instantiate different element sizes in the last level (dimension), as I posted before your reply. I already knew how to instantiated the values - String[][] str = new { {1,2}, {3} }. However, I couldn't figure out how to set by element. The crucial information here is that you can set only the first size dimension as in String[][] features = new String[firstLevel.length][], then associate the different element sizes. Note that the second dimension remains unset.

Answer (score 0):

While I waited for the answer, I found a way to solve the problem.

The relevant information here is that we do not need to set the second array dimension in its instantiation.

The code is below:

```
// INPUT string = "2-3,1,4-5"
private static String[][] featuresConversion(String string) {
    String[] firstLevel = string.split(","); // 1st lvl separator

    String[][] features = new String[firstLevel.length][]; // Sets 1st lvl length only

    int i = 0;
    for (String element : firstLevel) {
        features[i++] = element.split("-");
    }
        
    return features;
}
```

I want to thank you all. All suggested solutions also work fine!

Comment: Good answer except `String[][] features = new byte[firstLevel.length][];`. I assumed the dash meant a range from the lower number to the greater number. Example: `String input = "2-3,1,4-8";`

Comment: Ohhh sorry! In fact, my problem required conversion to bytes. I simplified my question here because I already knew how to convert it. I edited the code without compiling it. I already fix the byte issue! 

Concerning your range doubt, the dash only separate elements. The second level of separator must be different. Otherwise, I won't say if the element belongs to the first or second level. Thus, In your example, we will have { {2,3}, {1}, {4,8} }.

Comment: Yea, it just was not intuitive in your original question. Instead of `2-3`. I think you would have used something like `2-4`. Either way, I am glad you were able to solve the issue.